# Netbeans: how to open an command line on Windows

Tags: netbeans

Netbeans has a terminal window but it requires cygwin to be installed. Since I can't install cygwin (it requires admin permission), is there a way to open a Windows command line prompt(cmd) inside Netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin does need to be installed for NetBeans to have a **Terminal** window, and by default administrator rights are required to install it. However you can override that default requirement using the **--no-admin** argument when you install it.

See [section 2.4 of the Cygwin FAQs](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.noroot):

> 2.4.
>
> Can I install Cygwin without administrator rights?
>
> Yes. The default installation requests administrator rights because
>   this allows to set up the Cygwin environment so that all users can
>   start a Cygwin shell out of the box. However, if you don't have
>   administrator rights for your machine, and the admins don't want to
>   install it for you, you can install Cygwin just for yourself by
>   downloading setup-x86.exe (for a 32 bit install) or setup-x86_64.exe
>   (for a 64 bit install) and then start it from the command line or via
>   the "Run..." dialog from the start menu using the **--no-admin** option,
>   for instance:
>
> **setup-x86.exe --no-admin**

(While this is an answer, I am unfortunately not in a position to verify that it actually works.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Netbeans is closed while installing the Cygwin plugin, preferably download the . msi file for your PC's architecture(32 or 64 bits).
Thereafter Click on the tools bar above then you'll seen open in Terminal that should provide a terminal at the bottom of your Netbeans program.

Most importantly ensure your Netbeans is closed during installation.

Comment: This is not a solution since it ignores the issue of administrator rights mentioned in the OP.